# Get URLs of currently opened websites

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to retrieve information on currently opened websites in various web browsers with Python? The only thing I'm interested in is to get opened website URLs. I was looking into the selenium library, but I can't find anything that would help me achieve that.

Comment: Think there is not any inbuilt function to achieve it. You can try via browser extensions https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/

Answer (score 0):

"Dirty" hack to get URL from Chrome browser on Win platform. May not work properly due to interaction via mouse hotkeys.

```
import re
import time
import win32gui
import pyperclip
import pyautogui


class WindowMgr:
    def __init__ (self):
        self._handle = None

    def find_window(self, class_name, window_name=None):
        self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

    def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
        if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) is not None:
            self._handle = hwnd

    def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
        self._handle = None
        win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

    def set_foreground(self):
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)


def get_browser_url(browser_name):
    w = WindowMgr()
    w.find_window_wildcard(f'.*{browser_name}.*')
    w.set_foreground()
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'l')
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'c')
    return pyperclip.paste()


url = get_browser_url('Chrome')
```